# how to create List item like in simple alarm application that can"create/edit alarm" settings screen in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing my first android application that work same as, a "alarm clock" application does "create/edit alarm" phone-settings screens for every list item event.

what activities or classes that i should implement in order to do that ?

please suggest any "open source application " that i should follow in Oder to make it or pls share any simple  "alarm clock" application source code link(min sdk-17 platform)  thanks-alot

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Where are you stuck? Your question is currently far too broad for this site

Comment: i has just started,and i lack guidance how to do it,,please suggest any open source application that i should follow ,

Answer (score 0):

You can extends ListActivity. View more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: thanks ,,,please suggest any open source application that i should import and follow,like any simple "alarm clock "